# Jquery Effect- Fading

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there is a simple way to make a div fade in and slide to the right once the browser window is fully loaded and fade out and slide farther to the right if a link is clicked which takes the user to another part of the site . I don't know much about JQuery so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Start with (if you haven't already) an up-to-date [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials), searching through [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com) and then trying to implement this yourself. It's simple enough but not too simple for a beginner. You'll learn a lot more if you figure it out yourself than if you are just handed an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery documentation for animations.  There are [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods.

As for sliding, you'll want to check out the jQuery [animation and effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

More generally, you need to start out by reading [a good jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).  Trust me, it's not hard to start using effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) over `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` simply because the using `.fadeOut()` adds `display: none` when it's done.

This block of code on the .animate() page might help you get started...

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

In terms of having something happen when the user clicks a link (other than taking them to the page), you're going to want to use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#object').animate({opacity: 0.00}, 1).animate({opacity: 1.00, left: 50}, 'slow');

    $('#click').click(function(){

        var left = parseInt($('#object').css('left'));

        $('#object').animate({opacity: 0.00, left: (left + 50)}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/sKqnS/7/

Comment: He specified that he wanted to click on a _link_, so `$('#click').click()` would not work without `preventDefault()`.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't replace a link with a span tag, even if it still works. Non-javascript users and search engines will not be happy.